# Взаимодействие MySQL и SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Хочу написать простое crud приложение, но возникли вопросы

1. через http запрос контроллер должен найти значение в базе, но что то идет не так
2. как вернуть второе связанное значение из базы

Исходники
База

```
create table weather_history
(
  id            bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
  weather_date  date         not null,
  weather_value varchar(100) not null
);
```

Класс для взаимодействия с базой

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="weather_history")
public class Weather
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="weather_date")
    private String weatherDate;
    @Column(name="weather_value")
    private String weatherValue;
}
```

Репозиторий

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather,Long>
{
    List<Weather> findByWeatherDate(Date weatherDate);


}
```

Сервис

```
@Service
public class UserService
{

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository=userRepository;
    }

    public Weather findById(Long Id)
    {
        return userRepository.getOne(Id);

    }
    public List<Weather> findAll()
    {
        return userRepository.findAll();

    }
    public Weather saveUser(Weather user)
    {
        return userRepository.save(user);

    }
    public void deleteById(Long Id)
    {
        userRepository.deleteById(Id);

    }
    public List<Weather> findByWeatherDate(Date weatherDate)
    {
        return userRepository.findByWeatherDate(weatherDate);

    }
}
```

Ну и сам контроллер

```
public class UserController
{
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/check")
    public String check(@RequestParam String date) throws Exception
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        format.applyPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");
        Date docDate= format.parse(date);
        List<Weather> users=userService.findByWeatherDate(docDate);

        if (users.contains(date))
            return ???? вернуть weather_value из базы;
        else return "incorrect";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код `users.contains(date)` следует переписать.

1. Переименовать `List<Weather> users`, чтобы было какое-то корректное название, хотя бы `weatherList`
2. Проверка `contains` в данном случае бессмысленна, так как проверяется наличие объекта `Date` в списке объектов `Weather`, кроме того, репозиторий сам отфильтрует объекты `Weather`, если дата не будет найдена, вернется пустой список.
3. Поскольку репозиторий может вернуть список из нескольких элементов, нужно решить, объединить ли эти несколько ответов, используя к примеру Stream API `Collectors::joining`, или вернуть первый элемент.

```java
@GetMapping("/check")
public String check(@RequestParam String date) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.applyPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");
    Date docDate = format.parse(date);
    List<Weather> weatherList = userService.findByWeatherDate(docDate);

    if (weatherList.isEmpty()) {
        return "incorrect: no weather found for date " + date + " / " + docDate;
    }
    return weatherList
        .stream() // Stream<Weather>
        .map(Weather::getWeatherValue) // Stream<String>  поток weather_value
        .collect(Collectors.joining("; ")); // объединить в строку с делимитером "; "
}
```

---

Вернуть первое подходящее значение `weatherValue`:

```java
@GetMapping("/check")
public String check(@RequestParam String date) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.applyPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");
    Date docDate = format.parse(date);
    List<Weather> weatherList = userService.findByWeatherDate(docDate);

    if (weatherList.isEmpty()) {
        return "incorrect: no weather found for date " + date + " / " + docDate;
    }
    return weatherList.get(0).getWeatherValue();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, тольга все равно ругается "Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-12-12"] with root cause"

Comment: Значит, дата на входе имеет формат `yyyy-MM-dd`, а не `yyyy.MM.dd`, как указано в первоначальном коде контроллера.

Comment: Все это менял, не запускалось, как убрал код с Date все заработало, тип данных даты в классе у меня строка
    @Column(name="weather_date")
    private String weatherDate; Что странно в базе создавал date. В репозитории тоже поменял на строку.

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйtтеь для `weatherDate` тип `java.sql.Date`. Не следует путать с `java.util.Date`, который соответствует типу Date в MySQL).

Чтобы конвертировать `String` в `java.sql.Date` достаточно вызвать статический метод `Date.valueOf(String)`.